# Нужно проверить не превышает ли длина числа 10 элементов

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно проверить не превышает ли длина числа 10 элементов.
Использую `getElementById`, но не работает, в чем проблема?
Плюс оно перепроверяет только то, что ввели на клавиатуре, а как сделать дополнительную проверку ввода нажатиям кнопки?

```js
function checkLength() {
  var input = document.getElementById("t"); {
    if (input.value.length == 10) {
      input = input.replace(input, '');
      alert("Only 10 numers");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkLength();" placeholder="Enter data">
```

Comment: Свойство `maxlength` уже не даёт ввод более 10-ти символов, что же ещё надо?

Comment: maxlength для клавиатуры,а как тогда проверять события ввода через кнопку?

Comment: Эм... Через какую 'кнопку'?

Comment: у меня есть калькулятор,числа которые я ввожу через кнопки не проверяет,а числа которые ввожу клавой проверяет,как сделать что бы при вводе с кнопок выполнялась проверка поля input на maxlength?

Comment: Может в постановке задачи надо было намекнуть что используешь экзотический ввод, смекаешь? Ответ нормальный никто не даст, т.к. неизвестно что за калькулятор, что он ещё делает и почему там что-то не работает. Добавь описание этого калькулятора в вопрос.

Comment: Рекомендовал бы вам не выполнять действие нажатие на КНОПКУ калькулятора если длина символов в инпуте равна 10. это и решит все проблемы

Comment: если ты собираешься отправлять эти данные на php, то не стоит делать проверку на js, т.к можно просто удалить эту функцию и все. Проверяй на backend.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простейшая проверка:

```js
function checkLength(e){
  if(e.value.length > 10){   // Если больше 10
    e.value = '';            // Очищаем поле (вроде же так задумывалось?)
    alert("Only 10 numers"); // Выводим сообщение
  }
}

function isAllowedSymbol(e){
  return true; // Заглушка
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkLength(this);" placeholder="Enter data">
```